# split csv column entry on space using python

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to create a new csv file using python. The new csv file will be the same, but have one entry split based on a space delimiter.

My method is to open the files with read and write access respectively, skip over the headers, then write out the specific column headings I want in the csv.

Then iterate over each rows amending the appropriate section and writing the row to the new file using the `.writerow` function.

One iteration over the row creates 
`['data1', 'data2', 'data3 data4', 'data5', 'data6', 'data7' etc. ]`

So in this case I'm selecting `row[2]` to select the `'data3 data4'` part and trying to split these to create a list that looks like `['data1', 'data2', 'data3', 'data4', 'data5', 'data6', 'data7' etc. ]`

I have tried using `.split` which gives me a list within a list, I've tried `.slicing` which means I can show either `data3` or `data4`. I've also tried the `.replace` which gives me `['data1', 'data2', 'data3,data4', etc.]`. I'm quite frustrated and wondering if anyone might give me the a hint as to the probably quite simple solution that i'm missing. Full code is below.

```
import csv

with open('filepath', mode="rU") as infile:
    with open('filepath', mode="w") as outfile:

        csv_f = csv.reader(infile)
        next(csv_f, None)  # skip the headers

        writer = csv.writer(outfile)
        writer.writerow(['dataheader1', 'dataheader2', 'dataheader3', 'dataheader4', 'dataheader5', 'dataheader6', 'dataheader7' etc. ])

    for row in csv_f:
        row[2] = row[2].replace(' ', ',')
        print row
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
row[2:3] = row[2].split(' ')
```

Demonstration:

```
>>> row = ['a', 'b', 'c d e f', 'g', 'h']
>>> row[2:3] = row[2].split(' ')
>>> row
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']
```

Comment: You are my hero, would you mind telling me with the `row[2:3]` bit did?

Comment: That is the slice: start at index 2 and go to (but not including) index 3.  A slice can be assigned to just like a single index.

Comment: it reassigns the slice `[2:3]` in row, which is just the second element. If you used `row[2]` instead, you'd get `['a', 'b', ['c', 'd', 'e', 'f'], 'g', 'h']`. Assigning to the slice tells the interpreter that you want that to be part of the existing list.

Comment: Thank you very much, so close, yet so far.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know where the cells with spaces are, then you're looking for `itertools.chain.from_iterable`

```
import csv

with open('filepath', mode='rU') as infile,
     open('filepath2', mode='wb') as outfile:  # this changed slightly, look!
    csv_f = csv.reader(infile)
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    next(csv_f)  # skip headers
    row = next(csv_f)
    # row looks like
    # ['one', 'two', 'three four', 'five', ...]

    rewritten_row = itertools.chain.from_iterable(
        [cell.split() for cell in row])  # or map(str.split, row)
    # rewritten_row looks like
    # ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', ...]

    writer.writerow(rewritten_row)
```